# Underscore gives error in function

Tags: php

I have a FOR that runs the following line:

```
        for ($x=1;$x<=10;$x++) 
    {
        $result=$question[$x]."<br /><b>Correct Answer: ".$question[$x]_answer."</b><br />";
        echo $resultado;
    }
```

If I change the **$question[$x]_answer** to **$answer[x]** for example, everything works. So my question is, why doesn't it work if I have it with the underscore after the [x]. The part about **[x]_answer**. Is there a problem with underscore after having a **[x]** in a variable?

Comment: What would you expect `$question[$x]_answer` to be? What is your array called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a perfectly valid question. I don't see any reason for the downvotes.

This is what you would use: `${$question[$x].'_answer'}`.

Let me explain with an example,

```
$a[1] = 'user';
$b = 1;
```

So,

```
$a[$b] == 'user'; //true
```

And if

```
$user_ans = 'success';
```

We can use that like

```
${$a[$b].'_ans'} == 'success'; //true
```

As @DavidHoude pointed out in the comment, this is an example of  **[Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)**

Comment: +1 for this answer. This is a variable variable, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: *What advantage does using variable-variables have?* Almost every other language has decided there are *better ways* to solve this problem .. so thus if there is *no good advantage* (for task X), why use variable-variables (for task X)? In this case I would argue that they *are not appropriate* to cleanly approach/handle this problem.

Comment: Exactly. I was just answering the OP's question.

Comment: (I'm not downvoting this, of course, because it answers the question, but *why* do it like this?)

Comment: Many thanks. Maybe I was in sleep state but did not notice the array symbols there.

Answer (score 3):

`$question[$x]` refers to an array with $x being the index.

i.e:

```
$question[0] = "How old are you?";
$question[1] = "Male or Female?";
```

The way you have it, `$question[$x]_answer` is not a valid [variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), the index must come at the end. You cannot have [ or ] in a variable name.

Maybe try renaming your variable to `$question_answer[$x]` if you have an array of answers.

i.e:

```
$question_answer[0] = "12";
$question_answer[1] = "Male";
```

or you can use a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) if you hard-named your variables with the index already:
i.e:

```
$question_0_answer = "12";
$question_1_answer = "Male"
```

For this, you would use: `$question_{$x}_answer`

Answer (score 0):

`_` has no special meaning in php and hence is just like any other standard character. Your logic is identical to any of the following

```
$question[$x]Qanswer
$question[$x]Aanswer
etc...
```

None of these are valid because a variable cannot use `[`, `]`, or `$`(these are special).

e.g., you can't have variables like `$my[var` or `$my$var`.

So `$question[$x]_answer` either looks like a single variable to php but with invalid tokens in it(the `[$x]`) or it looks like an array, `$question[$x]` with some weird thing attached to it(like a space is missing or dot).

e.g.,

```
$question[$x] answer
$question[$x].answer
```

look like more valid things(the last one is probably what you want).